# drop shadow around border of UITextView to give it 3d effect in iOS/swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, shadow

Is there a way to drop a shadow around the border of a UITextView to give it a 3D effect?  The textView has rounded corners.

I don't want to drop a shadow for the content of the textView (i.e. text).  Just around the textView border only.

I need to clipToBounds on the textView for the rounded corners.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: textView.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath
shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2
textView.layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: add your tried code.

Comment: edited to reflect what I have tried

Comment: So code is not working? I mean shadow is not appearing?

Comment: shadow appears but covers whole textView

Comment: Comment the fillColor and `textview.backGroudColor = white`. And check with `fillColor= white`

Comment: textView backgroundColor is already white and commenting fillColor results in the whole textView completely black

Comment: Change fillcolor to white not clear.

Comment: with fill color white the entire textView is white and the text cannot be seen.  also shadow no longer appears

Comment: Make sure textview text color is black.

Comment: yes.  it is black.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason :** `Clips to bounds = true` and `shadow` on the same view doest not work simultaneous. So to sort out this you have to do follow.

1. Add your `TextView` in a UIView (says `viewTextBG`).
2. `TextView` Constraints : top bottom, leading, trailing = 0 wrt. `viewTextBG`.
3. Give corner radius to `textview` and `viewTextBG`

   ```
   textview.cornerRadius = 10
   viewTextBG.cornerRadius = 10
   ```
4. Give clipsToBounds to `textview` and `viewTextBG`

   ```
   textview.clipsToBounds = True
   viewTextBG.clipsToBounds = false
   ```
5. Now give shadow to `viewTextBG`.

Now everything works, thats all.